# I have an SN7489N Memory IC which is not lighting-up an LED whose positive-end is connected to one of the output pins via a 220 Ohms resistor

Tags: ttl, ram

CHIP Used: SN7489N F 9013 BS

[EDIT] I'm willing to light-up an LED at the output of the chip when the data stored is high, just as noted in a 74LS189 chip (and seen in this video : https://youtu.be/uYXwCBo40iA?t=690).
But it is only possible when I dont use any inverter and directly connect an LED's negative end to the output pin. If I use an inverter and connect the output pin to positive end of the LED, it doesn't light-up, which makes me wonder. I am using 74LS06N hex inverter.[/EDIT]

[image]

Things I've tried/made sure:

a) Positive side of the LED is connected to the output and the other end to the GND (even have tried reversing it but in vain).
b) Data stored is a LOW signal to get an inverted HIGH output.
c) Chip select/Memory enable is always low.
d) Write enable is held low at various time ranges (0.1s to 3s).
e) Write enable is held high after writing.
f) I've fixed address pins at 0000 and even 1111 at times.
g) I've held D1, D2, D3 at LOW and D4 at HIGH by jumpers.
h) I've made sure all inputs to the chip pins are working and voltage across the IC's Vcc and GND pin is 5v.
i) I've tried two SN7489N ICs so far, but in vain.

Some observations are:

When writing a HIGH signal to get LOW output, the LED lights-up when its negative side is connected to the output and the other end to +5V.

When holding both Write-enable and Chip-select HIGH, LED lights-up when I do not connect GND pin to GND (or connect it to HIGH).

I used multimeter to measure the HIGH output voltage and the maximum I have read so far is 0.28 volts. What am I missing?

Comment: You are missing that it can't provide enough current to light an LED

Comment: Can you please direct me to a source? I read datasheets for SN7489N (http://www.datasheets360.com/pdf/-5841186990476824375) and 74LS189 (http://www.datasheetspdf.com/pdf/614430/FairchildSemiconductor/74LS189/2). Which readings do I need to refer? I have read that a 7-segment LED requires at least 20mA to light-up correctly. I have even tried lighting it up without 220 Ohm resistor but in vain.

74LS189 was my reference, but due to non-availability in the market, I bought SN7489N chips and most likely, these chips are not tri-state buffered output ones.

Comment: look for the high level output current it can provide.

Comment: Look for Ioh in the datasheet.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Your question requires every reader to draw your circuit diagram in their head from your description. Please can you edit your post and add your schematic - the online schematic editor is a breeze to use. The clearer and better your question is, the better the quality of the answers it will attract. Again, a warm welcome to the site.

Comment: It is just 20 uA. So, the output pins of this chip are required to be connected to the negative end of the LED which will light-up the LED when data stored is 0 (assuming I am using a hex inverter to get actual data i.e. 0 in final output)? Isn't it weird to light-up the LEDs when data stored is a low-bit?

Comment: @TonyM Sure and thanks. I will add the schematic diagram soon. I will need some time to do it.

Comment: I remember getting excited in my apprenticeship when I found a 7489 in the TTL chip draw. That was 1976.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 7489 has open-collector outputs, so it can't provide ANY current at all from an output pin into a load when set to logic 1. This mechanism allows you to build larger memories by combining the outputs of multiple 7489s together in the days before the introduction of tri-state outputs on the later 74189.

Also, the 7489 and the 74189 have inverted outputs, so storing and retrieving a logic 1 in a location would result in the output being driven low, which works perfectly for your application as you simply need to wire your LED from +5V through a resistor to the output pin.

Although the datasheet doesn't specify a maximum low level output (sink) current (i.e. current into the output pin from the LED when active), it does specify the maximum output voltage you can expect for IOL values of both 12mA and 16mA, so you can assume that these values are safe to use.

So just alter your LED wiring and the device should work fine without the need for added buffer chips or transistors.

Comment: This is the concept I was exactly looking for. Now I think I have a better understanding of what an open-collector means (i.e. it can sink (collect) the current when an external load is connected via a pull-up resistor but it cant source current, which is why I was not able to light-up an LED connected to the HIGH output. Am I right?

Comment: Spot on. In general, TTL chips are a little counter-intuitive even without the complication of open-collector outputs. TTL inputs assume a logic high level unless you sink current OUT of them to ground to set them to a logic 0. So TTL outputs are designed to sink a lot more current than they can source because that's what they generally have to do.

Comment: Yes. I remember TTL chips assuming HIGH states when the pins were not connected to anything. Just when I was about to give-up, everything has started making sense. Credit goes to all of you. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

Output high cannot provide enough current. Try using output low to sink current through the LED. Apparently it can sink 1.6mA, so it should light a high efficiency LED. Use a resistor to limit the current to around 1mA. You will obviously need to invert the memory contents.

Comment: Hi Dirk. I read  that datasheet for Iol which is showing 12 mA (http://www.datasheets360.com/pdf/-5841186990476824375), so I have tried lighting-up the LED by connecting it to the negative end of the 7-segment display while the common anode is connected to 5v and it is lighting-up the LED (as also noted in my question's description under 'Observations').

Just curious, you said output low current is 1.6 mA, it is Iol right?

Comment: @TravelServe You need to look at High-level input current, and Low-level input current. I believe those other currents eg 12mA, is when everything is shorted out, which is not exactly functional